# how can i join tables by dates?

Tags: sql, mysql

I try to get an amount by joining id and date, but I get an error in the group and the join clause.

The expected result is to bring the amount for the max date and lastdate from table 2 (so I would double join to table2 to get the amount for each date).

I tried first to get the amount for max date but don't have any idea why it is kicking an error.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    max(a.date) AS maxdate,
    max(a.date) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS lastdate,
    b.amount
from 
table1 as a
left join table2 as b
on a.id = b.id and max(a.date) = b.date
group by a.id
```

Comment: Your query is invalid because you want to select `b.amount` without grouping by it. You must either add it to the `GROUP BY` clause or put it in an aggregate function like `SUM`, `MAX` etc. You should please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then improve your question as explained there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you are trying to use max(a.date) as a join condition, which results in an error because aggregate functions such as max cannot be used directly in join conditions:

```
ON a.id = b.id AND max(a.date) = b.date
```

Comment: thanks i had to do a nested query to replace max(a.date)

Comment: @Seph77 Since both your sample data and the exected result of your query are unknown, it is very difficult if not just impossible to see what you changed and if this was the best way. Keep in mind other people might have similar issues, find this question and hope to find an answer. Currently, they won't. So please improve your question. And you can also answer your own question and then share the query you used.

Answer (score 0):

To get the amount for the maximum date you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(table2.amount) AS amount
FROM
  table2
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(table1.date) AS max_date FROM table1) AS t1 ON t1.max_date = table2.date
GROUP BY
  table2.date
```

If you don't need to get the total amount, you can use a query without GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  table2.amount
FROM
  table2
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(table1.date) AS max_date FROM #table1) AS t1 ON t1.max_date = table2.date
```